# How to handle ASP MVC Url Parameter containing forward slash

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on a ASP.Net MVC project.
 I have a particular controller action that accepts a date value in the form yyyy/mm/dd. So the URL becomes

```
http://localhost/MyProject/PublicReview/GetReviews/2012/10/29.
```

where GetReviews is an action and 2012/10/29 the parameter. 
My RouteConfig is as follows:

```
     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
```

How should I change the routevalues ? What should be the order of MapRoute values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested this, but I'm guessing this will work in your scenario:

```
 routes.MapRoute( 
           "Reviews", "PublicReview/GetReviews/{year}/{month}/{day}" 
            { controller = "PublicReview", action = "GetReviews" };
```

Note that this will need your `GetReviews` method to have three properties of "year", "month" and "day". You'll then have to parse them into a `DateTime`.

Taken from http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs which uses "-" for date separators.

Comment: Thanks, It didn't work initially. Then I added the controller name to the url parameter: "PublicReview/GetReviews/{year}/{month}/{day}" Now it is working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it working. I'll update my answer with that extra parameter for other people in the same boat.